# AuthContext change after reload the page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

My `AuthContext` changes after reloading the page. I'm using typeScript. The `<AuthProvider>` is around my routes

Here is my createAuth code:

```js
import { createContext, ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextType);

type User = {
    email: string;
    name: string;
    password: string;
    avatar: string;
}

type AuthContextType = {
    user: User | undefined;
    singIn: (userGet: User | undefined, password: string) => Promise<void>;
}

type AuthProvider = {
    children: ReactNode
}


export function AuthProvider(props: AuthProvider){
    const [ user, setUser ] = useState<User>();

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(user){
            const {email, name, password, avatar } = user;
    
            setUser({
                email: email,
                name: name,
                password: password,
                avatar: avatar
            })
        }

    }, [])

    async function singIn(userGet: User | undefined, password: string) {

        if(!userGet){
            //code to render if user doesn’t exist
        }else{
            //bcrypt Stuff
        }
    }


    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, singIn}}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

And here is my context hook:

```js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";

export function useAuth(){
    const value = useContext(AuthContext);

    return value;
}
```

Here are my routes:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          //my routes
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How do you use `useAuth`? "code to render if user doesn’t exist" doesn't look in place for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Context API isn't going to persist data across page reloads. It persists data as you navigate between routes. If you want data to persist across page reloads here are a couple of options you have:

1.) Store the data on the server and make the necessary API calls

2.) Store the data within browser storage (local storage, session storage, etc.)